# How to merge and pipe results from two different commands to single command?

Tags: command-line

I want merge (union) output from two different commands, and pipe them to a single command.

A silly example:

Commands I want to merge the output:

```
cat wordlist.txt
ls ~/folder/*
```

into:

```
wc -l
```

In this example, if wordlist.txt contains 5 lines and 3 files, I want `wc -l` to return 8.

```
$cat wordlist.txt *[magical union thing]* ls ~/folder/* | wc -l
8
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Your *magical union thing* is a semicolon... and curly braces:

```
    { cat wordlist.txt ; ls ~/folder/* ; } | wc -l
```

The curly braces are only grouping the commands together, so that the pipe sign `|` affects the combined output.

You can also use parentheses `()` around a command group, which would execute the commands in a subshell. This has a subtle set of differences with curly braces, e.g. try the following out:

```
    cd $HOME/Desktop ; (cd $HOME ; pwd) ; pwd
    cd $HOME/Desktop ; { cd $HOME ; pwd ; } ; pwd
```

You'll see that all environment variables, including the current working directory, are reset after exiting the parenthesis group, but not after exiting the curly-brace group.

As for the semicolon, alternatives include the `&&` and `||` signs, which will conditionally execute the second command only if the first is successful or if not, respectively, e.g.

```
    cd $HOME/project && make
    ls $HOME/project || echo "Directory not found."
```

Comment: That does work!  Help me learn - what exactly are the curly braces doing in here?  What other magical powers do they have?

Comment: @DavidOneill `{ list; }` is a *compound command*. From `bash(1)`: *list is simply executed in the current shell environment.  list must be terminated with a newline or semicolon. [..] The  return status is the exit status of list.*

Comment: I've added a bit more info to the answer. The definitive guide to shell scripting with bash is the bash manpage, type `man bash` from the command line and browse it.

Comment: should the ; in those commands not be && in case the file wordlist.txt does not exists?

Comment: If `wordlist.txt` does not exist an error from `cat` will appear on standard error, but not on standard output, so `wc -l` will not count any lines from it. Same goes for `~/folder` not existing. One could add `2> /dev/null` between each of these commands and their semicolon to prevent noise on standard error, but other than being ugly, error messages are harmless for the purpose of counting lines.

Comment: yes but now the user is confident and tries to parse a file and tries to remove the content of that with an rm... suddenly the ; looks very scary.

Comment: Which is why I described the `&&` and `||` operators. The semicolon is appropriate in the `cat ; ls` example though.

Comment: Note the mandatory space: Works: `{ cat f.txt;ls -l;}|wc -l`, Syntax Error: `{cat f.txt;ls -l;}|wc -l`

Comment: If using the fish shell, replace `{` with `begin;` and replace `}` with `end`. So the example would be: `begin; cat wordlist.txt ; ls ~/folder/* ; end | wc -l`

Answer (score 9):

Since `wc` accepts a file path as input, you can also use process substitution:

```
wc -l <(cat wordlist.txt; ls ~/folder/*)
```

This roughly equivalent to:

```
echo wordlist.txt > temp
ls ~/folder/* >> temp
wc -l temp
```

Mind that `ls ~/folder/*` also returns the contents of subdirectories if any (due to glob expansion). If you just want to list the contents of `~/folder`, just use `ls ~/folder`.

Comment: The `wc -l` was just a made up example, i'm actually piping it into something more complicated that doesn't have this option.

Comment: @DavidOneill Well, as `cat` accepts a file argument, you can use `cat <(cat wordlist.txt; ls wordlist.txt) | wc -l` and even `cat wordlist.txt <(ls wordlist.txt) | wc -l`. This is of course very ugly, but it demonstrates the endless possibilities with command line tools.

Comment: @DavidOneill Correct, I've corrected it now, thanks.

Comment: You want `ls ~/folder/` so that if `~/folder` is a symbolic link `ls` lists the contents of its target instead of the link itself. By the way, all the `ls` commands should be followed by `-1` so that a single file per line is printed and `wc -l` is a valid way of counting files.

Comment: @pablomme You're true about the symlink thing, but `-1` is implied as the output is not a terminal but a pipe.

Comment: You're right, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I was asking myself the same question, and ended up writing a short script.

`magicalUnionThing` (I call it `append`):

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /dev/stdin
$*
```

Make that script executable

```
chmod +x ./magicalUnionThing
```

Now you do

```
cat wordlist.txt |./magicalUnionThing ls ~/folder/* | wc -l
```

What it does:

- Send standard input to standard output
- Execute argument. `$*` returns all arguments as a string. The output of that command goes to script standard output by default.

So the stdout of magicalUnionThing will be its stdin + stdout of the command that is passed as argument.

There are of course simpler ways, as per other answers.
Maybe this alternative can be useful in some cases.