# Trying to pass two variables in a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to make the following script work for the `ufw` command which is expecting me to press y or n to confirm my command. In addition I want to pass my password to the `sudo` command (I know, bad idea).

```
echo 'y' | { echo 'my password'; } | sudo ufw reset
```

The `sudo` password bit works but I get the following error message from the `ufw reset` command:

```
Resetting all rules to installed defaults. Proceed with operation (y|n)? Aborted
```

The command is being aborted rather than accepting the 'y' I was trying to send it. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Very bad idea indeed ... But here you go: https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line

Comment: @RoVo thank you the quick reply. If I understand that link you sent me it only covers passing a single variable (in this case the password). In my situation I not only want to pass my PW to Sudo, I also want to pass 'y" to ufw reset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge and pipe results from two different commands to single command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133386/how-to-merge-and-pipe-results-from-two-different-commands-to-single-command)

Comment: Passwords on a command line is always a bad idea. I'd rather do something like `echo y | ssh root@::1 ufw reset`. In order to not use an unencrypted key for root access you could use an encrypted key and load it into `ssh-agent`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're piping the `y` to `echo 'my password'`, not to `sudo`.

Use the block to group both the echos:

```
{ echo 'my password' ; echo y ; } | sudo ufw reset
```

`sudo` normally reads the password from a terminal, not stdin, unless you supply the `-S` option.

Comment: this is the wrong way round ;-) first the `password`, then the `y` ;-)

Comment: sure that it works  without the `-S` and with first printing `y`, then `my_password`? Maybe you should try again in a new terminal window where you haven't been logged into `sudo` before and see that it won't work...

Comment: Acutally @RoVo, you are correct. { echo 'passsword' ; echo 'y' ; } | sudo -S ufw reset - that works.

Comment: still missing the `-S`

Comment: You know what interesting is that it only works once. If you run the same command a second time in the same terminal window, you get the "aborted" message again. Not that it matters, I only need to run it once, but it's strange.

Comment: @RobertBaker: That's becuase sudo caches the password and doesn't ask for it the second time.

Comment: You can kill the cache with `sudo -k`.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve it like this:

```
printf '%s\n%s\n' 'your_password' 'y' | sudo -S ufw reset
```

or with `su -c`:

```
printf '%s\n' 'your_password' | sudo -S su -c "{ yes | ufw reset; }"
```

- This uses the nice little tool [`yes`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47344/what-is-the-point-of-the-yes-command) instead of `echo y`.
- I prefer `printf` instead of `echo` for unknown strings. -> [See this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

> Note: This is really a bad idea.
>   Better to add `ufw` to NOPASSWD list in `sudoers` file. [See here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password).
>   Or if you want to run that command repeatedly/automatically, you may instead [add it as root cronjob](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419548/how-to-set-up-a-root-cron-job-properly).

Comment: thanks for the tip about the yes tool, I will look into it. Also the NOASSWD tip.